# Zoho CRM Python SDK v2 initialization problem for Django

Tags: django, sdk, crm, zoho

Im trying to integrate the Zoho CRM v2 SDK with my Django app.
On the Django runserver, im able to get access tokens and using the refresh method and store them in the zcrm_oauthtokens.pkl file.  The sdk then automatically refreshes the access token using the refresh token, so no problem here.  However on my production server (heroku) im getting this error message:

```
2019-01-16T11:07:22.314759+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-01-16 11:07:22,314    - Client_Library_OAUTH - ERROR - Exception occured while fetching oauthtoken from db; Exception Message::'NoneType' object has no attribute 'accessToken'
```

It seems to me that the tokens are being saved to file, but when the sdk try to access them it is looking for them in a DB and not the file specified in the token_persistence_path.

In my settings.py I have this:

```
ZOHO_CLIENT_ID = config('ZOHO_CLIENT_ID')
ZOHO_CLIENT_SECRET = config('ZOHO_CLIENT_SECRET')
ZOHO_REDIRECT_URI = config('ZOHO_REDIRECT_URI')
ZOHO_CURRENT_USER_EMAIL = 'jamesalexander@mylastwill.co.uk'
ZOHO_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'wills_online', 'zoho')

zoho_config = {'apiBaseUrl': "https://www.zohoapis.com",
               'currentUserEmail': ZOHO_CURRENT_USER_EMAIL,
               'client_id': ZOHO_CLIENT_ID,
               'client_secret': ZOHO_CLIENT_SECRET,
               'redirect_uri': ZOHO_REDIRECT_URI,
               'token_persistence_path': ZOHO_PATH}
```

and in a views file I have this:

```
from zcrmsdk import *
import logging
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from wills.models import PersonalDetails, ZoHoRecord, WillDocument
from wills_online.decorators import start_new_thread
from wills_online.settings import zoho_config
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ZohoRunOnce:
    def __init__(self):
        self.already_run = False

    def run_once(self):
        if not self.already_run:
            print('zoho init run once')
            ZCRMRestClient.initialize(zoho_config)
            self.already_run = True

zoho_init = ZohoRunOnce()
zoho_init.run_once()
print(zoho_config['token_persistence_path'])


def zoho_callback():
    return HttpResponse(200)

@start_new_thread
def zoho_personal_details(request):
    """ updates or create a user account on zoho on profile completion """

    personal_details_ob = PersonalDetails.objects.get(user=request.user)
    zoho_ob = ZoHoRecord.objects.get(user=request.user)

    try:
        if zoho_ob.account:
            record = ZCRMRecord.get_instance('Accounts', zoho_ob.account)
            record.set_field_value('Account_Name', request.user.email)
            record.set_field_value('Name', personal_details_ob.full_name)
            record.set_field_value('Email', request.user.email)
            record.set_field_value('Address_Line_1', personal_details_ob.address_line_1)
            record.set_field_value('Address_Line_2', personal_details_ob.address_line_2)
            record.set_field_value('Post_Town', personal_details_ob.post_town)
            record.set_field_value('Post_Code', personal_details_ob.post_code)
            record.set_field_value('Dob_Day', personal_details_ob.dob_day)
            record.set_field_value('Dob_Month', personal_details_ob.dob_month)
            record.set_field_value('Dob_Year', personal_details_ob.dob_year)
            record.set_field_value('Gender', personal_details_ob.sex)
            record.set_field_value('Marital_Status', personal_details_ob.marital_status)
            record.set_field_value('Partner_Name', personal_details_ob.partner_full_name)
            record.set_field_value('Partner_Gender', personal_details_ob.partner_gender)
            record.set_field_value('Partner_Email', personal_details_ob.partner_email)
            record.set_field_value('Children', personal_details_ob.children)
            record.set_field_value('Pets', personal_details_ob.pets)
            record.update()
        else:
            user = ZCRMUser.get_instance(name='James Alexander')
            record = ZCRMRecord.get_instance('Accounts')
            record.set_field_value('Account_Owner', user)
            record.set_field_value('Account_Name', request.user.email)
            record.set_field_value('Name', personal_details_ob.full_name)
            record.set_field_value('Email', request.user.email)
            record.set_field_value('Address_Line_1', personal_details_ob.address_line_1)
            record.set_field_value('Address_Line_2', personal_details_ob.address_line_2)
            record.set_field_value('Post_Town', personal_details_ob.post_town)
            record.set_field_value('Post_Code', personal_details_ob.post_code)
            record.set_field_value('Dob_Day', personal_details_ob.dob_day)
            record.set_field_value('Dob_Month', personal_details_ob.dob_month)
            record.set_field_value('Dob_Year', personal_details_ob.dob_year)
            record.set_field_value('Gender', personal_details_ob.sex)
            record.set_field_value('Marital_Status', personal_details_ob.marital_status)
            record.set_field_value('Partner_Name', personal_details_ob.partner_full_name)
            record.set_field_value('Partner_Gender', personal_details_ob.partner_gender)
            record.set_field_value('Partner_Email', personal_details_ob.partner_email)
            record.set_field_value('Children', personal_details_ob.children)
            record.set_field_value('Pets', personal_details_ob.pets)
            response = record.create()
            # save account id to db for future updates
            zoho_ob.account = response.details['id']
            zoho_ob.save()

    except ZCRMException as ex:
        logger.log(1, ex.status_code)
        logger.log(1, ex.error_message)
        logger.log(1, ex.error_details)
        logger.log(1, ex.error_content)
        print(ex.status_code)
        print(ex.error_message)
        print(ex.error_content)
        print(ex.error_details)
```

Ive tried running  ZCRMRestClient.initialize(zoho_config) in settings.py, with no luck.

My method for getting the access token and refresh token, which seems to work is:

```
import os
import pprint
from sys import argv

import django
import requests
import zcrmsdk
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'wills_online.settings')
django.setup()


def zoho_refresh_token(code):
    """ supply a self client token from the zoho api credentials from web site """

    zoho_config = {"apiBaseUrl": "https://www.zohoapis.com",
               "currentUserEmail": settings.ZOHO_CURRENT_USER_EMAIL,
               "client_id": settings.ZOHO_CLIENT_ID,
               "client_secret": settings.ZOHO_CLIENT_SECRET,
               "redirect_uri": settings.ZOHO_REDIRECT_URI,
               "token_persistence_path": settings.ZOHO_PATH}

pprint.pprint(zoho_config)

print('working')
address = f'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token?code={code}&redirect_uri={settings.ZOHO_REDIRECT_URI}&client_id={settings.ZOHO_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={settings.ZOHO_CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=authorization_code'
response = requests.post(address)
data = response.json()
pprint.pprint(data)
zcrmsdk.ZCRMRestClient.initialize(zoho_config)
oauth_client = zcrmsdk.ZohoOAuth.get_client_instance()
refresh_token = data['refresh_token']
print(type(refresh_token))
oauth_client.generate_access_token_from_refresh_token(refresh_token, settings.ZOHO_CURRENT_USER_EMAIL)

print(refresh_token)
print('finished')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    zoho_refresh_token(argv[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, you will need to define `persistence_handler_class` and `persistence_handler_path` in your configuration dictionary. You will also need a handler class and a user-defined model to store the results. Sample code follows:

```
# settings.py

import zcrmsdk
configuration_dictionary = {
    'apiBaseUrl': 'https://www.zohoapis.com',
    'apiVersion': 'v2',
    'currentUserEmail': ZOHO_CURRENT_USER_EMAIL,
    'sandbox': 'False',
    'applicationLogFilePath': '',
    'client_id': ZOHO_CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': ZOHO_CLIENT_SECRET,
    'redirect_uri': ZOHO_REDIRECT_URI,
    'accounts_url': 'https://accounts.zoho.com',
    'access_type': 'online',
    'persistence_handler_class': ZOHO_HANDLER_CLASS,
    'persistence_handler_path': ZOHO_HANDLER_PATH,
}
zcrmsdk.ZCRMRestClient.initialize(configuration_dictionary)

# zoho.models.py

from django.db import models
from zcrmsdk.OAuthClient import ZohoOAuthTokens


class ZohoOAuthHandler:
    @staticmethod
    def get_oauthtokens(email_address):
        oauth_model_instance = ZohoOAuth.objects.get(user_email=email_address)
        return ZohoOAuthTokens(oauth_model_instance.refresh_token,
                               oauth_model_instance.access_token,
                               oauth_model_instance.expiry_time,
                               user_email=oauth_model_instance.user_email)

    @staticmethod
    def save_oauthtokens(oauth_token):
        defaults = {
            'refresh_token': oauth_token.refreshToken,
            'access_token': oauth_token.accessToken,
            'expiry_time': oauth_token.expiryTime,
        }
        ZohoOAuth.objects.update_or_create(user_email=oauth_token.userEmail, defaults=defaults)


class ZohoOAuth(models.Model):

    refresh_token = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    expiry_time = models.BigIntegerField()
    user_email = models.EmailField()
```

In this example `ZOHO_HANDLER_CLASS = 'ZohoOAuthHandler'` and `ZOHO_HANDLER_PATH = 'zoho.models'`

The first time you go to use this you will need a `grant_token` from https://accounts.zoho.com/developerconsole. For the scope use `aaaserver.profile.READ,ZohoCRM.modules.ALL` to start (see https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/oauth-overview.html#scopes)

Before you can use the api you'll need to run the code below in a django shell. This uses a grant token to generate your initial access and refresh tokens. Afterwards, the api should handle refreshing your access token.

```
grant_token = GRANT_TOKEN
import zcrmsdk
oauth_client = zcrmsdk.ZohoOAuth.get_client_instance()
oauth_tokens = oauth_client.generate_access_token(grant_token)
```